# Unexpected outcome, manipulating string on Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing some code in Python, trying to clean a string all to lower case without special characters.

```
string_salada_russa = '    !!   LeTRas PeqUEnAS &    GraNdeS'

clean_string = string_salada_russa.lower().strip()


print(clean_string)

i = 0

for c in clean_string:
  if(c.isalpha() == False and c != " "):
    clean_string = clean_string.replace(c, "").strip()


print(clean_string)

for c in clean_string:
  if(i >= 1 and i <= len(clean_string)-1):
    if(clean_string[i] == " " and clean_string[i-1] == " " and clean_string[i+1] == " "):
      clean_string = clean_string.replace(clean_string[i], "")
  i += 1


  
print(clean_string)
```

Expected outcome would be:

```
#original string
'    !!   LeTRas PeqUEnAS &    GraNdeS'

#expected
'letras pequenas grandes'

#actual outcome
'letraspequenasgrandes'
```

I am trying to remove the extra spaces, however unsucessfully. I end up removing ALL spaces.

Could anyone help me figure it out? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: This is probably because you shorten `clean_string` while iterating over it. A better strategy might be to iterate over `clean_string` and copy the letters you want to keep to another string (or even better, to a list, which you then join together when you're done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to strip your string at each iteration of the first for loop; but, other than that, you could keep the first piece of your code:

```
for c in clean_string:
    if (c.isalpha() == False and c != " "):
        clean_string = clean_string.replace(c, "")
```

Then split your string, effectively removing all the spaces, and re-join the word back into a single string, with a single space between each word:

```
clean_string = " ".join(clean_string.split())
```

Comment: Do note that this will be somewhat inefficient, since the whole string will be copied at each iteration when there is an invalid char.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `re`?

```py
import re

s = '    !!   LeTRas PeqUEnAS &    GraNdeS'
s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", s.lower()).strip()
print(s) # letras pequenas grandes
```

This first translates the letters into lower case (`lower`), replace each run of non-alphabetical characters into a single blank (`re.sub`), and then remove blanks around the string (`strip`).

Btw, your code does not output `'letraspequenasgrandes'`. Instead, it outputs `'letrasZpequenasZZZZZgrandes'`.

Answer (score 2):

You could get away with a combination of `str.lower()`, `str.split()`, `str.join()` and `str.isalpha()`:

```
def clean(s):
    return ' '.join(x for x in s.lower().split(' ') if x.isalpha())


s = '    !!   LeTRas PeqUEnAS &    GraNdeS'
print(clean(s))
# letras pequenas grandes
```

Basically, you first convert to lower and the split by `' '`. After that you filter out non-alpha tokens and join them back.